# Cant compare the String value of spinner selection

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-spinner

I have a very weird problem that i cant think any other solution as i tried almost everything.
I have a custom spinner:

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }

}
```

In my activity everything works fine and i have in every change the TOAST message. But when i want to compare the selsected string value to run some code, i dont get the String selsection except the first time (the default value)

```
user_gender = String.valueOf(gender_spinner.getSelectedItem());

if(user_gender.equals("Female")){
            Toast.makeText(NewUserActivity.this, "Female", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(NewUserActivity.this, user_gender, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I have the toast message onItemSelected from the customListener but i dont have the Toast message from the comparison.

I ll apriciate any help on this!

Comment: Try  user_gender = gender_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: Nope, same problem. Maybe i need to post all the activity as it must be something really stupid. I dont think its something wrong with my code. I have 3-4 days trying to solve it with no luck. Thanks for the help anyway!